# Grammartical error in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

I was reading How to Solve It by George Polya when the sentence bellow confused me:

> It may happen that a student hits upon an exceptionally bright idea
>   and **jumping all preparations** blurts out with the solution.

I don't understand the function of the three words in bold, and it seems that that three words just mess up the whole sentence.

I thought I am missing something.

Comment: Your cited text isn't really idiomatic (George Polya wasn't a native Anglophone, as you probably know). His ***jumping*** is a non-standard alternative to more natural terms such as ***by-passing, skipping, dispensing with***. His use of ***preparations*** is also very "odd" here. I assume he means ***the simple logical (preparatory) steps that ineluctably lead to an answer or proof***, as in a maths test where you might be required to show your "working out" steps rather than just an actual numerical answer. Finally, he shouldn't have included ***with*** after ***blurts out***.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about an example of natural use of English.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers that the sentence is not idiomatic English, although I only really have a problem with the **with** after **blurts out**.  **Jumping** could be viewed as a personal slang of **skipping**.

Comment: It is not good English. Polya was in his fifties when he arrived in the US, and Magyar is not closely akin to English. The participial phrase is a classic case of a misplaced modifier and relates to "student." Moreover, what is needed is not a participle, but rather a verb. In context, however, it is clear what this means, namely  "a student has a bright idea,  jumps over these preparatory steps, and blurts out the correct answer."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, but it was published by Princeton Press, and it should have been revised by some Anglophone. What a pity..

Comment: @JeffMorrow: what do you find to be misplaced about the participial phrase? I would mark it off with commas, but otherwise find nothing at all wrong with its syntax.

Comment: @ColinFine "jumping ..." relates to "student," but is separated from it. Modifiers belong close to the noun being modified.

Comment: @JeffMorrow. I see. I don't agree. "Jumping..." is after "and", and so is part of the predicate "blurts out [with] the solution". I don't see it as modifying the subject  "student", but the predicate.

Comment: @ColinFine Can blurts jump? Can answers jump? It is the student who jumps over the preparatory steps that Polya is advocating. However, whether it is a misplaced modifier substituting for a verb or some other defect is not as significant as the recognition that the sentence is defective.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: Yes, "student" is the subject of the predicate. Do you find "a student, jumping all preparations, blurts out" to be malformed? I agree that the the sentence is defective in other ways.

Comment: @ColinFine It seems to me that you have just proved that your definition of a misplaced modifier and mine differ. We agree that "student" is the word being modified. And it is a fact that the modifying phrase is not adjacent to the word being modified and so is difficult to construe. I am not, however, going to argue definitional differences. If "jumping over ...." had followed "student" the sentence would have been far clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not idiomatic. However, if you replace ***jumping*** with its synonym<sup>[1]</sup> ***skipping***, it becomes idiomatic. Alternatively, make it ***jumping over*** and it might not be how most native speakers would say it, but it would be understandable. This defect is not entirely surprising given that Polya was not a native English-speaker, and probably didn't even work mainly in the English language until late middle age.

What he means is that the student manages, through some stroke of inspiration, to see the solution without taking the expected steps of reasoning from the problem statement to the answer. As such, ***preparations*** isn't the best choice of word either, but his meaning is reasonably clear if you know the subject and the language well enough to figure out what he *meant*.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>: Bearing in mind that synonyms are frequently not entirely identical in meaning.